# AWS GLue Run Time VS. Amount of Data

Tags: aws-glue

I keep seeing the following lines within my job run over and over.  Job never finishes, and coincidentally, pulls significantly less tables and data than my co-workers job that finishes within 5 minutes.

```
 18/06/14 12:01:38 DEBUG Client: client token: N/A diagnostics: N/A ApplicationMaster host: 999.99.99.99 ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0 queue: default start time: 1528976771600 final status: UNDEFINED tracking URL: http://ip-999-99-9-999.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1528975883916_0001/ user: root
```

Since documentation on GLUE is still fairly sparse, not sure exactly where I should look.

Code is below:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.window import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pprint import pprint

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'TempDir'])

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session

## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "snapshots", table_name = "data_prospect", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>"]
## @return: <output>
## @inputs: []
# data_prospects = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="snapshots", table_name="data_prospect", redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx="<transformation_ctx>")
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "snapshots", table_name = "data_prospect", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>"]
## @return: <output>
## @inputs: []
data_visitor_activitys = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "snapshots", table_name = "data_visitor_activity", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

data_prospects = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "snapshots", table_name = "data_prospect", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

sf_contacts = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "snapshots", table_name = "sf_contactfile", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

dataactivities_df = data_visitor_activitys.toDF()
dataactivities_df.createOrReplaceTempView("dataactivitiestable")
dataactivities_dfsql = spark.sql("select campaign_id, created_at, type, id from dataactivitiestable where type IN (6,11)")
data_visitor_activitys = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataactivities_dfsql, glueContext, "new_dynamic_frame")

dataprospects_df = data_prospects.toDF()
dataprospects_df.createOrReplaceTempView("dataprospecttable")
dataprospects_dfsql = spark.sql("select crm_lead_fid, crm_contact_fid, id from dataprospecttable ")
data_prospects = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataprospects_dfsql, glueContext, "new_dynamic_frame")

sfcontacts_df = sf_contacts.toDF()
sfcontacts_df.createOrReplaceTempView("contactstable")
sfcontacts_dfsql = spark.sql("select AccountId,id from contactstable")
sf_contacts = DynamicFrame.fromDF(sfcontacts_dfsql, glueContext, "new_dynamic_frame")

## @type: RenameField
## @args: [old_name = "<old_name>", new_name = "<new_name>", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>"]
## @return: <output>
## @inputs: [frame = <frame>]
data_visitor_activitys = RenameField.apply(frame = data_visitor_activitys, old_name = "campaign_id", new_name = "campaignidfull__c", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
data_visitor_activitys = RenameField.apply(frame = data_visitor_activitys, old_name = "created_at", new_name = "CampaignAdoptedDate__c", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
data_visitor_activitys = RenameField.apply(frame = data_visitor_activitys, old_name = "id", new_name = "CampMemId", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

# datava = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_visitor_activitys, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/datava"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

data_prospects = RenameField.apply(frame = data_prospects, old_name = "crm_lead_fid", new_name = "LeadId", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
# dataprospects = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_prospects, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/datapros"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

sf_contacts = RenameField.apply(frame = sf_contacts, old_name = "accountid", new_name = "acctnumber", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
sf_contacts = RenameField.apply(frame = sf_contacts, old_name = "id", new_name = "leadorcontactownerid", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
# sfcontacts = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = sf_contacts, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/contacts"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")


data_join_1 = Join.apply(frame1=data_visitor_activitys, frame2=data_prospects, keys1=['prospect_id'], keys2=['id'], transformation_ctx="<transformation_ctx>")
datajoin1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_join_1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/datajoin1"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

data_join_2 = Join.apply(frame1=data_join_1, frame2=sf_contacts, keys1=['crm_contact_fid'], keys2=['id'], transformation_ctx="<transformation_ctx>")
# datajoin2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_join_2, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/datajoin2"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

pardor_final_join = Join.apply(frame1=data_join_1, frame2=sf_contacts, keys1=['crm_contact_fid'], keys2=['id'], transformation_ctx="<transformation_ctx>")
DataFINAL = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_join_2, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://bucket/glue/prospect/MTA/datafinal"}, format = "avro", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
```

Comment: How many DPUs are you using?  The first thing to try is to increase that number.  It's possible that the data set you're trying to process is too large for the default number of DPUs.

Comment: @BobSwain I had actually increased it to the maximum which was 100 and it still failed.  The kicker is that the amount of data is able to be processed within SQL Server with no issues, but Glue can't seem to finish the job.  I ended up filtering it all the way down and dropping a ton of columns to get it to finish.

Comment: Can you post the Glue script?  If you're doing a .collect() that can slow things down quite a bit.

Comment: @BobSwain Code added. Sorry for delay.